# Deploy the same app multiple times

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am attempting to deploy the same application (same WAR file) multiple times (as multiple CloudFoundry apps).  I would just add instances but I want to provide different environment variables for the two different apps.  I am able to vmc push the first copy fine.  It starts and runs as expected.  The second time I attempt to deploy the app, however, I receive the following error:

```
Uploading app_name... FAILED
Upload failed. Try again with 'vmc push'.
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash
```

When I look in the crash file as specified, it provides the following stack trace:

```
Time of crash:
  2013-03-11 22:19:41 -0500

TypeError: can't convert nil into String

multipart-post-1.1.5/lib/composite_io.rb:84:in `initialize'
multipart-post-1.1.5/lib/composite_io.rb:84:in `open'
multipart-post-1.1.5/lib/composite_io.rb:84:in `initialize'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/v1/base.rb:57:in `new'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/v1/base.rb:57:in `upload_app'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/upload_helpers.rb:48:in `upload'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:86:in `block in upload_app'
interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:85:in `upload_app'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:53:in `sync_app'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:46:in `push'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/base.rb:66:in `run'
...
```

What am I missing?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to run the command in the dir contains the war. Also check whether you are using the manifest xml saved during the previous deployment.

Comment: I am running it from the dir that contains the war (target from my maven build) and I am not saving my configuration (does that matter?).  I've also tried copying the war into another directory and running vmc from there with no luck.

Comment: i need more info like what is the version of your vmc and what is the steps/screen logs when doing the "vmc push".

Comment: Update.  It seems that this is an issue.  I've logged it here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vmc/issues/65

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a vmc issue and was fixed lately. Details can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vmc/issues/65.